# How can I use MQTTnet in UWP JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, windows-10, mqtt

I have a JavaScript UWP application and I need to use MQTT library to communicate with my device.

I choose the [MQTTnet](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet) library because it supports the **Universal Windows Platform (UWP) 10.0.10240+ (x86, x64, ARM, AnyCPU)** according to the description.

When I'm installing the NuGet package it's downloading a lot of dependencies and fails on this step:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit.1.0.3' does not exist in project 'StreamSocket'
```

StreamSocket is my test project based on the [project from Windows universal samples collection](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket/js).

I tried to create a RuntimeComponent project in the same solution, added the NuGet reference to MQTTnet there. And I added the reference to this project from the StreamSocket project.

I can build the project now but now I've got the runtime error:

```
0x80070002 - JavaScript runtime error: The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MQTTnet.Core, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This issue should be caused by the third-party package. I saw you open a issue [here](https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/issues/111), you could wait for the author's reply.